# Is there a way to find out the origin of the javascript code which makes a post request to my server?

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, web-services

I have a RESTful web service that's implemented using(Jax-Rs) running on Wildfly 10. Say I have a second webapp running on some simple web server. That second webapp consists of html and javascript.

Ley's say that the second app is hosted on the IP address x.x.x.x, and the client access that webpage from his IP address: y.y.y.y.

Now, what actually happens is the javascript code that is served as part of my second webapp makes an Ajax call to the RESTful web service hosted on my Wildfly server(that is on a separate domain/IP).

The javascript code looks something like this

```
$.post( 'z.z.z.z', { redirect_uri: "http://x.x.x.x/test.html", grant_type: "authorization_code", code: 'known_authz_code', client_id: "test_id", client_secret: "secret" } )
    .done(function( data, status ) {
        // some code here
    });
```

Now, I know that the javascript code is downloaded and executed in the browser, so I suppose that the IP address my Wildfly server(where the RESTful web service is hosted) would see the IP address of the client that uses the browser(y.y.y.y) and not the IP address of the web server from where the javascript file originated(in this example x.x.x.x).

1. Is this correct?
2. If it is, is there a way my Wildfly server can know the origin from where the javascript file that called the RESTful web service originated(in my example x.x.x.x)? Or it can just see the IP address of the device from which the browser made the request(in my example y.y.y.y)?

Answer (score 0):

1. It is correct.
2. To my knowledge, you have absolutely no mean of finding the IP of which server the Javascript containing the Ajax originated from, just from the request. What you would want to do however, is including the IP of the server that generates the JS in the parameters of your Ajax request, before it is served to the client's browser.